# How can I capture all link clicks after a page is loaded and new links are added?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm very new to JS, jQuery, and JSON in general, so there's probably several things wrong with what I'm trying to do here, and I'm likely fundamentally off base. Anyhow, what I want to do is capture all link clicks on a page, retrieve a JSON response, and then update the page accordingly. My code works when the page initially loads, but after I generate new content any links in the new content do not behave the same as the original links.

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var pageUrl = $(this).attr('href');
        $.getJSON(pageUrl, function (page){
            $('#pageData').slideUp(300, function(){
                $(this).html(page.block).css('margin-top', '10px').slideDown(300);
            });
        })
        .fail(function (){
            alert('fail no JSON');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use event delegation since you may have to deal with dynamic elements

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var pageUrl = $(this).attr('href');
        $.getJSON(pageUrl, function (page){
            $('#pageData').slideUp(300, function(){
                $(this).html(page.block).css('margin-top', '10px').slideDown(300);
            });
        })
        .fail(function (){
            alert('fail no JSON');
        });
    });
});
```